# How to merge text files using mapping and reducing in Java Spark MLLib?

Tags: java, apache-spark, svm, hadoop-yarn, apache-spark-mllib

I have a really large dataset stored on a Hadoop (YARN cluster) with on which I want to train a Support Vector Machine classifier.
Features are extracted from each data-point from the dataset and saved in [LibSVM](http://www.quora.com/What-is-this-data-format-in-LIBSVM-training-dataset) format.
Spark MLLib can read these files using [MLUtils.LoadLibSVMFile](https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.2.1/api/java/org/apache/spark/mllib/util/MLUtils.html)(JavaSparkContext context, String directory).
Every file has one line with doubles ending in a newline character. The line represents values of the features.

I want to concatenate all these files into a JavaRDD.
Can I use .textFile("../*") with somekind of .join or .union statement?
I do not understand how to do this ...

Could you please be so kind to help?
I think more people would like to know how to do this efficiently.

Answer (score 1):

`SparkContext.textFile("/path/to/file/*")` will read **all** the matched files and represent you a single large RDD.

And I think `MLUtils.LoadLibSVMFile(sc, "/path/to/file/*")` will load all your features for you. Have you tried?

Comment: You are right :) 
MLUtils.LoadLibSVMFile(sc, "/path/to/file/*") does indeed load all the features I need.

Do you maybe also know where I can find the RBF kernel version for Spark or some people with which we can make such an extension to the linear kernel already available?

Comment: I think people are already [work in on it](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-4638). I hope you have the patience :)

Comment: Thank you for the link! I have patience, but also want to contribute my knowledge :) But it is written in Scala, so I can probably not use it in Java? (I'm writing my code in Java)

Comment: Yes, you can. You can mix Java and Scala in one project, and many IDE can recognize and compile separately.

Comment: Do you perhaps know what the output of the SVMModel.predict() * means? The values, as seen below, make no sense to me. Also documentation is missing ...
*https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/java/org/apache/spark/mllib/classification/ClassificationModel.html#predict%28org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaRDD%29
-18.841544889249917  0.0
168.32916035523283  1.0
420.67763915879794  1.0
-974.1942589201286  0.0
71.73602841256813  1.0
233.13636224524993  1.0
-1000.5902168199027  0.0

Comment: @romusters, this is a different, you should open a new thread. For your question, the returned Double is the [label](https://spark.apache.org/docs/0.9.2/api/mllib/index.html#org.apache.spark.mllib.regression.LabeledPoint)

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I did indeed check the documentation, as a good student would always do first before asking questions ;) and found that it is the label. However, a class label of 168... does not belong to the available class which can be 1 or 0. I can see that if the score is closer to a 0 or 1, the label will also be the 0 or 1 respectively. I have started a new thread as you suggested :)
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30029863/what-does-the-score-of-the-spark-mllib-svm-output-mean