# What does the score of the Spark MLLib SVM output mean?

Tags: apache-spark, svm, probability, apache-spark-mllib

I do not understand the output of the SVM classifier from the Spark MLLib algorithm. I want to convert the score to a probability, so that I get a probability for a data-point belonging to a certain class (on which the SVM is trained, a.k.a. multi-class problem) [(see also this thread)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29989981/calculate-probability-mllib-svm-multi-class). It is unclear what the score means. Is it the distance to the hyperplane? How do I get the probabilities from it?

Comment: SVMs are deterministic and don't deal in probabilities, they only fit a decision boundary. You could certainly guess a probability based on the distance to the decision boundary, but it's doubtful how well it would work.

Comment: LibSVM does support it, as well as the scientific literature: www.citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.41.1639 So I think calculating the posterior probability is possible, but it is not available in Spark MLLib. Since I do not get any response from the community regarding such functionality being already available, I conclude that I have to implement it myself?

Comment: That link doesn't work.

Comment: Some more info [here](http://www.researchgate.net/post/Can_we_assign_probability_to_SVM_results_instead_of_a_binary_output2): *There is a technique to map the svm scores toward probabilities based on logistic regression. This technique was proposed by Platt et al. a couple of years ago and is availaable in many a decent svm implementation.
As it is only a post-hoc probability score wrapped around the final svm, some scientists criticize it as not being really probabilitic. For the latter, Gaussian processes might be used [...]*

Comment: Working link: http://www.researchgate.net/profile/John_Platt/publication/2594015_Probabilistic_Outputs_for_Support_Vector_Machines_and_Comparisons_to_Regularized_Likelihood_Methods/links/004635154cff5262d6000000.pdf

Comment: Exactly! Making clusters using Learning Vector Quantization, determining the spread function of a cluster with a Gaussian function and then retrieving the probability makes a lot more sense. Using the distances from the hyperplanes from several SVM classifiers and then trying to determine some probability on these distance measures, does not make any sense, because the distribution property of the data-points belonging to a cluster is not taken into account.
Does anyone see a fallacy in my reasoning?

Answer (score 1):

The value is the margin -- distance to separating hyperplane. It is not a probability, and SVMs do not in general give you a probability. However as comments by @cfh note, you can try to learn probabilities based on this margin. But that's separate from the SVM.

Comment: As you are author of: Co-author, Advanced Analytics on Spark, you probably know for certain if Spark MLLib includes the functionality of learning the probabilities. I could not find it.

If I may so free to ask: do you think LVQ makes more sense in multi-class classification and extracting the probability? I think it does because the distribution of points in the clusters can be models by a Gaussian function and this function can be used to calculate the probabilities. I hope you can give me some advice :)

Comment: Yes that's me. If you need to learn probabilities, use a model that does this directly like simple LR. You don't need probs for multiclass though. I dont really know LVQ but does that give probabilities? I dont think you're fitting Gaussians in any of these.

Comment: Good, yes I agree, however, logistic regression (LR) is not as powerful as a SVM with a RBF kernel (most of the times) in multi-class classification problems. So therefore I would like to know how I can calculate these probabilities. From your answer I can conclude that Spark's MLLib does not include the functionality of learning the probabilities?
In that case, I think it is more wise to use LVQ: https://onlinecourses.science.psu.edu/stat557/node/79
In this link, clouds of points with a colour can be found, these clouds can be fit with a Gaussian function and thus give the probabilities?

Comment: If you want to model data that looks like "multi-colored clouds" my advice is to make each cloud (i.e. class) a Gaussian bump and then derive posterior class probabilities via Bayes Rule.

Comment: Thank you Sean Owen and Robert Dodler. I have a clear idea what to do now.

Answer (score 1):

```
import org.apache.spark.mllib.classification.{SVMModel, SVMWithSGD}
import org.apache.spark.mllib.evaluation.BinaryClassificationMetrics
import org.apache.spark.mllib.util.MLUtils

// Load training data in LIBSVM format.
val data = MLUtils.loadLibSVMFile(sc, "data/mllib/sample_libsvm_data.txt")

// Split data into training (60%) and test (40%).
val splits = data.randomSplit(Array(0.6, 0.4), seed = 11L)
val training = splits(0).cache()
val test = splits(1)

// Run training algorithm to build the model
val numIterations = 100
val model = SVMWithSGD.train(training, numIterations)

// Clear the default threshold.
model.clearThreshold()

// Compute raw scores on the test set.
val scoreAndLabels = test.map { point =>
  val score = model.predict(point.features)
  (score, point.label)
}

// Get evaluation metrics.
val metrics = new BinaryClassificationMetrics(scoreAndLabels)
val auROC = metrics.areaUnderROC()

println("Area under ROC = " + auROC)

// Save and load model
model.save(sc, "myModelPath")
val sameModel = SVMModel.load(sc, "myModelPath")
```

If you are using SVM module in MLLib , they provide you the AUC which is area under ROC curve and it is equivalent to "Accuracy" . Hope it helps.