# Spark/Pyspark: SVM - How to get Area-under-curve?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-ml

I have been dealing with random forest and naive bayes lately. Now i want to use a Support vector machine.

After fitting the model i wanted to use the output columns "probability" and "label" to compute the AUC value. But now I have seen that there is no column "probability" for SVM?!

Here you can see how I have done so far:

```
from pyspark.ml.classification import LinearSVC

svm = LinearSVC(maxIter=5, regParam=0.01)
model = svm.fit(train)

scores = model.transform(train)
results = scores.select('probability', 'label')

# Create Score-Label Set for 'BinaryClassificationMetrics'
results_collect = results.collect()
results_list = [(float(i[0][0]), 1.0-float(i[1])) for i in results_collect]
scoreAndLabels = sc.parallelize(results_list)

metrics = BinaryClassificationMetrics(scoreAndLabels)
print("AUC-value: " + str(round(metrics.areaUnderROC,4)))
```

That was my approach how I have done this in the past for random forest and naive bayes. I thought I could do it with svm too... But that does not work because there is no output column "probability".

Does anyone know why the column "probability" does not exist? And how i can compute the AUC-value now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the most recent `spark/pyspark` to the time of this answer:

If you use the `pyspark.ml` module (unlike `mllib`), you can work with Dataframe as the interface:

```
svm = LinearSVC(maxIter=5, regParam=0.01)
model = svm.fit(train)
test_prediction = model.transform(test)
```

Create the evaluator (see it's source code for settings):

```
from pyspark.ml.evaluation import BinaryClassificationEvaluator
evaluator = BinaryClassificationEvaluator()
```

Apply evaluator to data (again, source code shows more options):

```
evaluation = evaluator.evaluate(test_prediction)
```

The result of `evaluate` is, by default, the "Area Under Curve":

```
print("evaluation (area under ROC): %f" % evaluation)
```

Answer (score 0):

SVM algorithm doesn't provide probability estimates, but only some scores.

There is an algorithm proposed by Platt to compute probabilities given SVM scores, but it's criticized but some and apparently not implemented in Spark.

Btw, there was a similar question [What does the score of the Spark MLLib SVM output mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30029863/what-does-the-score-of-the-spark-mllib-svm-output-mean)